# Permissions error fetching application - Gcloud app deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I am trying to deploy to a gcloud app (following the steps here: https://realpython.com/python-web-applications/). My gmail account is the owner of the project (and just to be safe, I've added lots of other roles like app engine deployer, viewer etc even though I think owner should cover all of them). When I enter "gcloud app deploy" I am getting the following error:

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application [apps/hello-app-389902]. Please make sure that you have permission to view applications on the project and that XXXX@gmail.com has the App Engine Deployer (roles/appengine.deployer) role.

I've tried re-authenticating, adding more roles and I keep getting the same error. I've googled but none of the solutions posted there worked for me

Comment: i think this is a authentication denied case, you should check your GCP project ID ,API Enablement. Or best you should ask ChatGPT its providing some options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Billing services were not enabled. Enabling billing services fixes this error

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm you're trying to deploy with the right account. Execute the command

   `gcloud config list account` to get the current account (email) that you're deploying with.
2. If the above is not the right email you're expecting, then set the right account (email) by executing

   `gcloud config set account <email>`
3. After executing steps 1 and/or 2 above, open a new shell/command prompt and then try deploying again (the key here is to try it again in a new shell/command prompt)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, with both my own email address, and with the app engine default service account. I opened a new shell, and tried to deploy again. I kept getting the same error message

Comment: Hi, just to confirm, you're saying that if you go to https://console.cloud.google.com and login with your own email address, you see the target project and app engine App. You also see that email as the owner. You also confirm that when you do ```gcloud config list account```, you see the same email listed. But when you deploy you get the error in your post?

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to this. I do see the target project when I login yes. I am not sure where to look for an app engine app (or even what that exactly is).  I searched for app engine but when I try to load that site, I keep getting a "failed to load" error (other parts of the site load fine)

Comment: I think I fixed it. Billing services were not enabled ... they REALLY could have made this obvious in so many different places. Thanks so much for your help anyway

Comment: Awesome!! It's actually good when you're able to solve your own problem. Gives you more confidence and you typically would have tried a bunch of things which then gives you knowledge of stuff that typically comes in useful later on

Comment: And yes, the error should have been more explicit. You can submit feedback about it to Google. Open the Google App Engine Standard documentation page and at the bottom, you'll find a button for 'send feedback'

Comment: Yeah I was tearing my hair out for hours here tbh ... Just hope this post helps someone else until Google hopefully improve the error message. And yes for sure will tell them about it. Thanks again

Comment: @AndrewC You should write it up as an answer and then accept it. That way, other people will know the solution (not everyone will read through comments and so might miss the solution)